# How can I set up an alias for "git last" that accepts a number as an argument?

Tags: linux, git, bash, git-config

In Pro Git Scott Chacon gives some nice examples of [some alias which might be helpful](http://progit.org/book/ch2-7.html), including one that shows the last commit: `git last` which is the equivalent of `log -1 HEAD`:

```
git config --global alias.last 'log -1 HEAD'
```

It will show something like this:

```
$ git last
commit 66938dae3329c7aebe598c2246a8e6af90d04646
Author: Josh Goebel <dreamer3@example.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 26 19:48:51 2008 +0800

    test for current head
```

I read a few similar questions on stack overflow like [Pass an argument to a Git alias command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/can-i-pass-argument-to-the-alias-of-git-command) but have not still not been able to figure this out.

The best I could come up with was to modify my `.gitconfig` file as follows:

```
[alias]
    last = log -1 HEAD
    mylast = "!sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/git last -$0 HEAD'"
```

Then if I run this at the command line:

```
$ git mylast 12
```

I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/git last -12 HEAD
```

That actually looks right. But if I remove the `echo` in front, it just hangs like it is waiting for input. I tried switching `$0` for `$1` but that didn't seem to help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to set it up so that if I just type `git last` with no number then it would default to "1" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
last = !sh -c 'git log "-${1:-1}" HEAD' -
```

This takes advantage of the [shell parameter interpolation default](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) syntax, `${var:-default}` which substitutes `default` if the variable `var` is not set.

Comment: nice! any way to get it set to 1 by default if no parameter is specified?

Comment: Sure. Change it from `$1` to `${1:-1}`.

Comment: (Also if you wanted, you could change the `HEAD` to `${2:-HEAD}` which would give you the ability to request `git last 2 <branch>` for an arbitrary branch.)

Comment: This is an excellent little alias, to do this on oneline (and avoid adding it to .gitconfig directly) the following works from a bash shell: `set +H` then `git config --global alias.last "!sh -c 'git log -\${1:-1} \${2:-HEAD}' -"`. Shell needs the exclamation mark and the dollars escaped.