# git alias not working properly

Tags: git, bash, alias

I have a git alias that is supposed to do a `git checkout -b <branchname>` (basically create the branch and check it out). My alias looks like:

```
newbranch = !sh -c 'git checkout -b "$1"'
```

But when I try `git newbranch mytestbbranch` I get an error saying that the "b" switch requires an argument.

I have a similar alias for rename that looks like:

```
rename = !sh -c 'git branch -m "$1" "$2"'
```

And that one works just fine. I'm confused why the `newbranch` alias isn't working.

Comment: Duplicate of [git alias with positional parameters (git foo aaa bbb ccc => foo aaa && bar bbb && baz ccc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters-git-foo-aaa-bbb-ccc-foo-aaa-bar-bbb) and [Pass an argument to a Git alias command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an alias like

```
!sh -c 'git checkout -b "$1"'
```

you should need an ending dash `-`:

```
!sh -c 'git checkout -b "$1"' -
```

I don't understand why your other alias works.

According to [Advanced aliases with arguments from the Linux Kernel Git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments):

> Starting with version 1.5.3, git supports appending the arguments to commands prefixed with "!", too. If you need to perform a reordering, or to use an argument twice, you can use this trick:
>
> ```
>  [alias]
>       example = !sh -c 'ls $2 $1' -
> ```
>
> The final dash is so that arguments start with $1, not with $0.

See also:

1. [git alias with positional parameters (git foo aaa bbb ccc => foo aaa && bar bbb && baz ccc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters-git-foo-aaa-bbb-ccc-foo-aaa-bar-bbb/3326971#3326971).
2. [Pass an argument to a Git alias command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command/7005698#7005698).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why the other one works either in that case...but with the trailing dash all works. I missed that line about the trailing dash.