# can I make a git alias from this?

Tags: git, parameter-passing, alias

In order to see what files I modified in the last period of time I use the following command:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="2 days ago" | sort | uniq
```

The thing is that I'll like to transform this into an alias. Can I pass the `2 days ago` as an argument to my alias command?

PS: I'm using Windows

Comment: You're talking about Bash aliases?  Why not just make a function?

Comment: Are you using `git-bash` under Windows? Or cmd.exe?

Comment: @merlin2011: I'm using git-bash

Comment: I believe the answer should work for you under git bash but I cannot test it because I currently don't have access to a windows system.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a **git alias** for some reason, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005698/391161) may help you.

However, as Oli's comment mentions, your problem is possibly better solved using a bash function since you are invoking external shell commands anyways. This function definition should be placed in your `.bashrc` so that it is defined every time you load a shell.

```
glog() {
   git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="$1" | sort | uniq
}
```

Invoke it on the shell like this:

```
glog "2 days ago"
```

Comment: You need to put this function in .bashrc (or if you using zsh in .zshrc). After recreating a terminal the function is available.

Comment: @Celt0, Good point. I thought that was implied but you are right that I should make it explicit.

Comment: You can also create a real Git alias out of this if you want by prefixing the command with a `!`, e.g. `git config alias.mylog '!git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="2 days ago" | sort | uniq'`. Now `git mylog` will run that string as a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create the desired alias.
I suggest to read this articel (it alos have link to many usefull aliases)

http://durdn.com/blog/2012/11/22/must-have-git-aliases-advanced-examples/

The artilce will show you how to write simple aliases along with some advanced git function as aliases.

Good luck.