# Variables inside Git Aliases

Tags: git

I am writing some aliases for git commands. The main purpose is for comparing commits, for example:

```
git config --global alias.compare "diff master..${some_branch}"
```

Is it possible to make something like this?

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead keep it this way:

```
git config --global alias.compare "diff master"
```

And use the command this way:

```
compare 7fe3b6
compare test-branch
```

Comment: You don't need to write `..` in the argument of `git diff`; `diff` operates on a pair of revisions, not on a range.