# git add and commit single tracked file in one command

Tags: git, alias

I'm looking for the equivalent of `git commit -am "blah blah"` but for just a single file.  If I try:

```
git commit my.file -am "blah blah"
```

I get:

```
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
```

I looked around but I could only find solutions that suggest using aliases (e.g. **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-a-git-commit-in-one-command)**), but even those don't seem like they could be modified because I need to pass an argument.  Do I have to resort to **[calling git through a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command)**?

It seems like there should be a simpler option for something that I imagine would be extremely common.  Right now I'm stuck with:

```
git add my.file
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just omit the `-a` which means `--all` which is not what you want.  Do this:

```
git commit my.file -m "blah blah"
```

That will commit only `my.file`, even if other files are staged (by `git add`).

Comment: Jeez, can't believe it was that simple.  I didn't realize I could commit without staging (the "Changes not staged for commit:" message threw me off).  No wonder no one else asked this question...  I also missinterpreted the -a to mean `add`.

Comment: This *will* commit the file even though it's not yet staged by `git add`. (I didn't believe that at first -- though it's mentioned both in question and in the above comment(!), so explicitly mentioning it here.)

Comment: However, if a file is yet untracked, this won't commit it.