# git submodule replacement that doesn't detach heads

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree, git-detached-head, git-subrepo

**My situation**: I have a large number of computers that I use for various tasks.  I have a large number of libraries, each in its own git repo.

**My desire**: I want to be able to modify one of the libraries on any computer, do a git commit/push; then go to another computer, do a `git pull`, and have all the libraries updated.  Then I modify one of these libraries, commit/push, and everything works when I get tot he next computer.

**My current attempt**:  I have a top-level git project that incorporates all the other library repos as submodules.  This includes a .gitmodules file that specifies the working branch of each module by using

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.modulename.branch develop
```

I have [`update = merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master) set for each module.
I have `submodule.recurse` set to true, so `git pull` at the top level does *something* to each module.

**How it is broken**: Heads become detached.  I wrote a script that parses the `.gitmodules` file and does a `checkout` of the appropriate branch of each module. I then `commit` and `push` the top module.  Whenever I modify things and try to do a pull, e.g. on another machine, heads become detached.  If I don't notice that the head is detached before I start modifications, I have to carefully unscramble the wreckage before I can commit my changes.

There are literally 3.6k stack overflow questions about git detached heads over the past decade, and most seem to be from the submodule capability.  I haven't gone through all of them, but what I have tried isn't working.

I forget why I rejected `git-subtree`, but `git-subrepo` hasn't been touched in over a year and has 153 issues and 25 pull requests pending, so I think it's dead.

Does anyone have a working solution to this?

---

## Accepted answer from @vonC looks good.

I could probably streamline this a bit, but my readme for the top-level project now says:

### Recommended checkout:

```
git clone --recursive --jobs=8 *mysuperproject_clone_url*
cd *mysuperproject*
git config alias.pullall 'submodule foreach git pull'
git config alias.statusall 'submodule foreach git status'
git config alias.switchall \
    "submodule foreach --recursive 'git switch \$(git config -f \${toplevel}/.gitmodules submodule.\${sm_path}.branch)'"
git switchall
```

#### Updating from repository

```
git pullall
```

#### If heads become detached, fix with

```
git switchall
```

#### To add a module

Module named `newmodule` working on path `develop` in the following example.

```
cd /path/to/mysuperproject
git submodule add git@github.com:myaccount/newmodule
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.newmodule.branch develop
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.newmodule.update merge
```

If the submodule is on the default `master` branch, you still have to config the branch.

If you switch a submodule to a different branch, then in the top level you must config again

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.newmodule.branch newbranch
```

And push both the submodule and the top level project.

On a different working directory (such as on a different machine), you must

```
cd /path/to/mysuperproject
git pull
git switchall
git pullall
```

Comment: There is an ongoing (but probably far-future-dated) project for reworking the "user experience" (UX) for submodules, but this really is how they're intended to be used: as detached-HEAD setups virtually all the time. The general idea is to avoid using branch names at all in the submodules, since branch names have negative functional value at that point.

Comment: What I mean by this is straightforward: a *branch name* represents the *latest* commit. A *submodule* in Git represents a *specific* commit. If that commit hash ID were to change just because some branch name somewhere changed, that would be incorrect behavior. So if a submodule is left "on" a branch, this is to be considered a deficiency. It may be a temporarily-necessary deficiency, but from the design-of-submodules point of view, it's a bug.

Comment: @torek so you are saying that submodules is not the appropriate tool for my (seemingly common) use-case.  The useful behavior is the incorrect behavior.  So the question is: is there a correct tool in git? Or can the available tool be perverted to do the job.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no correct tool. The Google folks wrote `repo` (the Python thing) to tackle this but seem to have abandoned `repo`, so apparently there's something deeply wrong with that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20797186/6309) that `git submodule update --remote --merge` is supposed to *not* detached the HEAD of a submodule following a branch.

I understand you have set `update = merge`, but just for testing, try the complete update command, to see if this works.

Since the HEAD is still detached, you need to add (to a git alias script for instance) the command

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git switch $(git config -f .gitmodules submodule.${sm_path}.branch)
```

I just tested it:

First, in the Git repository, I check the submodule is in a detached HEAD mode:

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ git submodule update --init
Submodule 'sha1collisiondetection' (https://github.com/cr-marcstevens/sha1collisiondetection.git) registered for path 'sha1collisiondetection'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/vonc/git/git/sha1collisiondetection'...
Submodule path 'sha1collisiondetection': checked out '855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2'


vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git/sha1collisiondetection (master)
$ git br
* (HEAD detached at 855827c)
  master
```

Then I define my alias, with escaped `$`: `\$`.
No need for `../` when accessing the `.gitmodules` file. That is what `$toplevel` is for.

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ git config alias.switchall \
    "submodule foreach --recursive 'git switch \$(git config -f \${toplevel}/.gitmodules submodule.\${sm_path}.branch)'"
```

Final test:

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ git switchall
Entering 'sha1collisiondetection'
Previous HEAD position was 855827c Detect endianess on HP-UX
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git (tmp)
$ cd sha1collisiondetection/

vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git/sha1collisiondetection (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/git/sha1collisiondetection (master)
$ git branch
* master
```

Comment: Answers in edit to question

Comment: @DMPalmer OK. I have edited the answer to propose a solution.

Comment: How and when would I do this?  Can I add a 'hook' in git so that every time I do anything it re-attaches all heads?

Comment: @DMPalmer You can define a git alias function which chains the two commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005698/6309

Comment: it isn't working for me, either because the ${sm_path} is being interpreted by my bash shell before git even starts, or because .gitmodules is not in the submodule's directory, or both.  The second can be fixed by using ../gitmodules, but I haven't foudn the right pattern of escapes to fix the second.  Alias: `switchall =  submodule foreach --recursive git switch $(git config -f ../.gitmodules submodule.${sm_path}.branch)` looks in `submodule..branch` each time.

Comment: Also, .git/config local to the top-level directory (as opposed to global '~/.git/config'), where I store the aliases doesn't seem to be something that can be placed under version control.  Should I just have those alias commands in my setup instructions or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @DMPalmer I just tested that alias. It does seem to work just fine. I have edited my answer to illustrate the steps I followed.