# Add commits before root commit in Git?

Tags: git, github, backup, commit

## New Question

Two questions:

1. I'm trying to put a commit before **ALL** commits.
   The bottommost commit has `660fb2a76211f36ec9a67d0454a90eab469e9fd0` as SHA. When I type `git rebase -i 660fb2a76211f36ec9a67d0454a90eab469e9fd0` every commit but the last one gets displayed in the list.
   I really need this commit to appear so I can put the very first commit as very last!
2. When I put the very first commit as first in the list *(meaning second commit in total, because the very first is not in the list as mentioned above)* I get an error: `error: could not apply b722c76... v1.4.3 BEAT release`
   I just cut it from the bottom of the list and put it to the top! **I did not change the number!**
   I also tried this several times. The same result.

That's it so far. If you have questions go ahead and ask!

## Original Question

I just dicovered old backups of my project. These backups where created before I used git.
I now would like to add them to my repository as old commits. That would mean I have to put these commit in front of **all** other commits.

Now there are several problems with this:

1. How do I in general put a commit before other ones?
2. How could I do this fast? *(I have many backups!)*
3. How do I set a date for these ***"old"*** commits? *(I know the dates of the backups!)*

If something is not clear, please mention it. I will fix the issue then!

One last thing:

I have published this on GitHub. And I mainly used their software to commit commits. So how do I push this back to GitHub?

Comment: Doing this involves rewriting the entire history of what you have so far.  If other people have unmerged work based off your current history, you'll cause a ton of conflicts with their code.  If such is the case, rewriting your entire history to have your old work come first in the commit graph is a bad idea.

Comment: This won't be a problem. I'm working on this alone. And I **do** understand that this means rewriting the entire history!

Comment: Are your backups just files?  Or are they from another version control system?

Comment: They are just folders.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

I found another, slightly simpler way to do this, using the `--root` flag of [`git rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).  I tried it out with a repo of mine, so I know it works (at least for a completely ***linear*** history, more on that at the end).

#### Step 1: Create a backup clone of your repo

Let's play it safe and make a backup, just in case we end up doing something disastrous and losing your data:

```
git clone original-repo backup-repo
```

#### Step 2: Create orphan branch (this will be your new root)

Checkout the orphan branch.  Specifying a start-point commit/branch is optional, if you leave that argument out, then Git will default to using your current commit as the start-point (it follows the pattern of standard branching syntax):

```
git checkout --orphan new-master firstCommitOfOldMaster
```

I specified the root of the old master as the start-point, because it will probably make the following step faster (removing the working directory files).

#### Step 3: Remove working directory files

Creating the orphan branch `new-master` from your old master might leave behind files in your working directory and index, depending on what the state of the files were in the commit you branched off of:

> The index and the working tree are adjusted as if you had previously run `git checkout <start_point>`. This allows you to start a new history that records a set of paths similar to `<start_point>` by easily running `git commit -a` to make the root commit. — [git checkout docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)

What you'll want to do now is to completely clear the state of the branch, so that you're really starting again from a clean slate (run from top level folder):

```
git rm -rf .
```

This is the explanation from the docs:

> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of paths that is totally different from the one of `<start_point>`, then you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating the orphan branch by running `git rm -rf .` from the top level of the working tree. Afterwards you will be ready to prepare your new files, repopulating the working tree, by copying them from elsewhere, extracting a tarball, etc.

#### Step 4: Recommit older work into `new-master`

Now you'll want to start commiting your older work into `new-master`.  When you're done, you'll rebase your old master on top.

I'm not exactly sure how your backup folders are organized, but I'm going to assume that each one is just a dated copy of your project folder, named in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, e.g. `2013-01-30`.  You can add the contents of each folder as a new commit manually, or you can write a script to automate the process.

Let's assume you have all your backup folders in a top folder called `backup` that sits in the same directory as your main project folder.  Then here is some pseudo-code for a script to automate the process of commiting each folder:

```ruby
# Get backups and sort them from oldest to newest
backups = open("backups").toList().sort("date ascending")
for each (backup in backups)
    copy files from backup to project folder
    execute `git add "*"`
    execute `git commit --date="#{backup.date}" --message="#{backup.date}"`
```

The script above will only add and modify files between commits.  If any of your backups deleted, moved, or renamed files, the script won't record that.  You'll need to write a more clever script to do that (maybe something that makes use of `git diff` or some other diffing tool), or record those changes manually.

#### Step 5: Rebase old `master` onto `new-master`

**BEHOLD THE AWESOME POWER THAT IS GIT!**  Now we're going to **REWRITE YOUR ENTIRE HISTORY!**  Recite these arcane words of power, and watch the magic happen!:

```
git rebase --onto new-master --root master
```

TA-DA!  You might have to resolve conflicts between the last-commit of `new-master` and the first-commit of `master`, but other than that, that should be it!

The `--root` flag to `rebase` gets around the problem we were having earlier about the fact that—normally—`rebase` won't operate on the first (root) commit of a Git repo.  The `--root` flag basically tells Git to include it in the `rebase`:

> Rebase all commits reachable from `<branch>`, instead of limiting them with an `<upstream>`. This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch. When used with `--onto`, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>` (instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without `--onto` it will operate on every change. — [rebase docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)

#### Step 6: Verify that final commit is still the same

Just to make sure we didn't mess any of the code up, we'll want to compare the current, final state of `master` to its state before we did the `rebase`.  Either of the following commands will work (they're identical).  While on the `master` branch:

```
git diff orig_head   # "Original" head
git diff master@{1}  # Master at its 1st prior position
```

If you get no output from the `diff`, then that means the final state of your rebased `master` is identical to what it was before the `rebase`.  Good job!

#### NOTE: not sure what happens to merge commits...

Now the above steps will work fine if you have a perfectly ***linear*** history, i.e. you don't have any merge commits.  I'm not sure if it will still work if you do.  In my previous answer below I mentioned that using the `--preserve-merges` flag with `rebase` might help you keep those merges, but the docs mention that that flag also interacts with the `--onto` and `--root` flags:

> When [`--root` is] used together with both `--onto` and `--preserve-merges`, all root commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead. — [rebase docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)

I'm not exactly sure what that means at the moment...I might have to try it out and see what happens.  Does it mean that if you have more than 1 root commit (like 10 for example), then 9 of those root commits will end up being rebased onto the last one acting as the new root?  That doesn't seem like the behavior we would want.  We just want to preserve merge commits for one root being rebased onto another.

---

### Previous answer

MGA had [the right idea with `rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762949/456814).  I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but maybe you need to make a new root commit in your repo, add your backup files as new commits on top of it, then rebase your old commit graph on top.

For example, `git checkout` has an `--orphan` flag according to [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> **`--orphan <new_branch>`**
>   Create a new orphan branch, named `<new_branch>`, started from `<start_point>` and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

So maybe you can try

```
git checkout --orphan <temp_branch>
```

Then commit your backup files to it.  Then with `temp_branch` checked out, do

```
git cherry-pick <first commit from master>
git rebase --onto temp_branch <first commit from master> master
```

I think you would probably need to `cherry-pick` the first commit because the 2nd argument to  `rebase --onto` is the old base of the branch you want to rebase (in this case `master`), and the old base isn't included.  So that's why I figure you need to `cherry-pick` it in order to get it, since it has no base commit itself, so you can't specify one for it in the `rebase`.

Also note that if your commit history isn't linear (i.e. it has merge commits), then `rebase` won't normally preserve those.  It has a `--preserve-merges` flag, but I've never used it before, so I'm not really sure of how it will work.  From [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> **`-p`**
>   **`--preserve-merges`**
>   Instead of ignoring merges, try to recreate them.
>
> This uses the `--interactive` machinery internally, but combining it with the `--interactive` option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

So, maybe all of that will work?

Comment: That's almost perfect! I'm going to see if there's anything not working. If so I'll come back later!

Comment: Ok. I made it work: First I have to make that new branch and make all the commits with the change in date. When this is done I make my working directory look like the first commit of my master branch. Then I make a commit which deletes all files. After that i do the rebase. The I do a rebase again and delete the commit which deletes all files and the original first commit of my master and done! Thank you **very** much!

Comment: @YannickSchinko so what I suggested basically worked? You just modified some of the steps?

Comment: Basically. These other steps are more or less necessary.

Comment: Just wanted to add a quick note here that git v.1.7.12+ has a `--root` option to interactive rebases (as noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git)). It allows you to rewrite the root commit, so it may be helpful as part of the solution.

Comment: I guess this is even better! You should post this as an answer!

Comment: I updated my original answer with the new info :)

Comment: Sounds impressive. +1

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use `git rebase`. In this case you could do the following:

First thing first, commit your old changes. Then:

```
$ git rebase --interactive master
```

This will open a file with your commits in a text editor. Just change the order of the commits (cut/paste your last commits to be the first ones, including the "pick" command on the left), save and close the editor.
At this point the rebase will begin. To continue when you're asked for confirmation, type:

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

Until it's all done. More information [here](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase).

2) I don't know any method to make this faster, but it should be pretty fast already.

3) To change the date of a commit you must change GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE.
For this there's a pretty example [in the accepted answer for this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git).

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I type the `git rebase --interactive master` command a wired screen opens, but not a text editor! (And the first line says "noop")

Comment: Uhm, here (I'm on Windows 7) a text editor is opened. What about git rebase --interactive HEAD~5 (replace the number with any number of commits you want to be shown)?

Comment: Ok. I fixed that. But keeps it saying "noop". It won't display any commits!

Comment: Even with git rebase --interactive HEAD~5 (see comment above)?

Comment: no. But I want to but first commit as last one. (I have 53 commits) I can type `git rebase --interactive HEAD~52` but not `git rebase --interactive HEAD~53`! That's my problem! And `git rebase --interactive master` gives me `noop` in the text file!

Comment: try `git rebase --interactive` followed by the hash of the root commit, like it's explained in the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363908/how-do-i-use-git-rebase-i-to-rebase-all-changes-in-a-branch

Comment: this still hast two issues: I **still** cant't see my initial post in the list! And it says `error: could not apply ...`. I just cut this from the front of the list an pasted it in the very first place!

Comment: At this point I don't really know how to help, sorry...